# Accessing C++ templates from C

Tags: c++, c, templates

I am using OpenCV for some image manipulation and it has several functions that must be given a data type to perform correctly. My idea is to template these functions so I do not have to write a separate function for each possible data type it could be.

However, the code I would like the code I am writing to be compatible with some existing C code I have that stores images in memory so I can pass it around easier without writing the image to disc constantly.

The problem I am running into is how to make my .h files and libraries to let the C program call the C++ template functions. I have not had a chance to try it yet, but so far what I have would look something what follows:

foo.h

```
int foo(int a, int, b);
float foo(float a, float b);
```

foo.c:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    return footemp(a, b);
}
float foo(float a, float b) {
   return footemp(a, b);
}
```

foo.hpp:

```
template<class t>
t footemp(t a, t b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

Which does not work since it requires my .c file to know about a templated file.
So I am open to suggestions. Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: There's also no overloading in C.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible, with some care. Use a C++ source file `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "footemp.hpp"

int foo_int(int a, int b) {
    return footemp(a, b);
}

float foo_float(float a, float b) {
   return footemp(a, b);
}
```

In `foo.h`, use `extern "C"` to make C-compatible declarations, with an `#ifdef` to allow use as *either* C or C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int foo_int(int a, int, b);
float foo_float(float a, float b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Compile this as a C++ library—static or dynamic, it doesn’t matter. In your C sources you can now `#include "foo.h"` and use these functions as you would expect, so long as you link against the library.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine one thing you could do is write the function in C++, declaring the specializations you want, and at the same time defining `extern "C"` functions that forward the calls to the template functions.

Keep in mind if you're using C for the other stuff, you're going to need to name the functions different; C doesn't do function overloading.

Answer (score 2):

As mday299 mentioned, there is no templates in C. 
However, if your C code is contained in a saparate compilation unit (.exe/.dll), you can provide C interface for your template functions almost like you did it:

foo.h

```
/* C interface */

    int fooInt(int a, int, b);
    float fooFloat(float a, float b);
```

foo.hpp

```
template <class T> foo(T a,T b)
{
return a+b;
}
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.hpp"
int fooInt(int a, int b) {
    return foo<int>(a, b);
}
float fooFloat(float a, float b) {
   return foo<float>(a, b);
}
```

Then, project would be compiled separate using c++, and c part would see only foo.h and lib/dll file

Answer (score 1):

No templates in C.  That's a C++ feature.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that you'll be able to compile your C file with a C++ compiler. So you can build your whole project, both C and C++ sources with a C++ compiler.

You are already compiling it with a C++ compiler, otherwise you wouldn't be able to compile your overloaded foo functions.

Comment: C++ is almost a superset of C.  If you can just compile your .c files as c++ (may require a special compiler flag or renaming them to .cpp/xx/c) that would probably be the easiest.